# Access Subform and Referencing

Tags: ms-access, vba

Why is this code not runninig.I want to return a `Mininimum (MIN_STOCK)` and `Maximum (Stock MAX_STOCK1)` and a `>quantity` in hand `QTY_IHND1` for a drug with number `(COMM_NUM)`.

```
If DCount(QTY_IHND1, "Stores_Table") = 0 Then
    QTY_IHND1 = 0

ElseIf DCount(QTY_IHND1, "Stores_Table") > 1 Then
     QTY_IHND1 = DLast("QTY_IHND1", "Stores_Table", "COMM_NUM = [COMM_NUM]") _
          + ((SubStoresTable.Form!QTY_RECVD) - (SubStoresTable.Form!QTY_ISSUE))
Else
     QTY_IHND1 = 0
End If

Forms!Pharmacytally.Controls("QTY_IHND1").Value = QTY_IHND1
MAX_STOCK1 = DMin("QTY_IHND1", "Stores_Table", "COMM_NUM" = [COMM_NUM])
Forms!Pharmacytally.Controls("MAX_STOCK1").Value = MAX_STOCK1
MIN_STOCK1 = DMin("QTY_IHND1", "Stores_Table", "COMM_NUM" = [COMM_NUM])
Forms!Pharmacytally.Controls("MIN_STOCK1").Value = MIN_STOCK1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where the subform part in your title comes into your question. There is an articles from the MVPs site [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm).

You have the equals in the wrong place.

```
 MAX_STOCK1 = DMin("QTY_IHND1", "Stores_Table", "COMM_NUM =" & [COMM_NUM])
```

COMM_NUM must be numeric, otherwise you need quotes.

The whole code section is not good, and could do with reworking. For example:

```
DCount(QTY_IHND1, "Stores_Table")
```

This seems to be a fairly odd check on whether the stores table is completely empty, also, QTY_IHND1 is not quoted.

```
DLast("QTY_IHND1", "Stores_Table", "COMM_NUM = [COMM_NUM]"
```

Comm_Num is always equal to itself.

In addition, you have so many look-ups, you would be better with a recordset.

Then there is the whole Last thing. Last is a very bad way to get a value except in a single user system and even then you should consider that it may not remain single user.

There is no need to refer to the control property to get a control:

```
Forms!Pharmacytally.Controls("QTY_IHND1")
```

Controls become properties of the form:

```
Forms!Pharmacytally.QTY_IHND1
```

Or

```
Forms!Pharmacytally!QTY_IHND1
```

Or if the code is running on the Pharmacytally form,

```
Me.QTY_IHND1
```

This will allow you to take advantage of intellisense.

EDIT re Comment

Working from the main form and a subform control named MySubformControl

```
 MyQty = Me.MySubformControl.Form.QTY_RECVD
```

It is important to note that MySubformControl is the name of the subform control, not the form contained.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am fairly new to this.I have COMM_NUM,QTY_IHND1, MIN_STOCK1, and MAX_STOCK1 on the main form.QTY_RECVD and QTY_ISSUE are  on a subform.If I want to call a field value from the subform when I am in the Main form which code will I use and vise versa. The MVP site is too confusing.I will be looking at Recordset I have not had any experience with that yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ,I have spent sometime learning Recordset as you suggested.I think it is a lot manageable.But I am sure this is basic how can I put the results from the Immediate window in VBA into a field on my form.Thanks in advance